# Is it possible to make multiple guides at once?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-cs5

Is it possible to make multiple guides at once in Photoshop?

If I click "Add new guide" and then enter a value, say, 20px. Is it possible to make a guide that is 20px off of every edge? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Workaround) **Actions**.

For the example you provided:

- Choose `Actions` window and `Create new action`
- `Image → Canvas size...`

  - [✓] `Relative`
  - `Width: -40 pixels`
  - `Height: -40 pixels`
- `View → New Guide...`

  - [✓] `Horizontal`
  - `Position: 0`
  - *repeat for vertical*
- `View → New Guide...`

  - [✓] `Horizontal`
  - `Position: 100%`
  - *repeat for vertical*
- `Image → Canvas size...`

  - [✓] `Relative`
  - `Width: 40 pixels`
  - `Height: 40 pixels`
- Choose `Stop` from the `Actions` window

---

If you want to enter the `Canvas size` (ie. "guide margin") value every time you run the actions, just tick the `Toggle dialog on/off` checkbox in the `Actions` window next to the `Canvas size` actions. (Remember to double the wanted "guide margin" length and start with negative lengths.)

---

**NB:** You might get black borders, if your file has data on the default `Background` layer. You could work this around by doing a `Duplicate Layer...` action on the `Background` layer as the first step in the action set.

---

<del>**NB2:** I'm currently on a computer with a rather old version of Photoshop (CS 1) and it translates the `100%` into pixel units ***before*** saving the data to the action. This might not be the case with CS 5, but I can't test it for the next two weeks.</del>

**EDIT!** The action will translate the typed units to whatever the `ruler unit` is set to. So, to save guides at "100%" in your action, change the `ruler unit` to `percent` just before adding new guides and aftewards back to pixels. You can change the unit back to what it was after you've saved the action — action will stay to use the percent value.

You can change the ruler unit from the `Preferences` or by second-clicking a ruler.

---

In order to get the action to work with documents with different resolutions, you must tick the `Toggle dialog on/off` checkbox in the `Actions` window next to the last two `Make → New Guide` actions.

Running the action Photoshop will ask for the guide positions, for which you will have to give the aforementioned `100%`. This way Photoshop will nag you with 2 dialogs, but it's quite automatic and faster than manually creating four guides.

Comment: Great Answer! I will select when I get this to work.

Answer (score 4):

For PhotoShop CC 2014, go to `View > New Guide Layout...`

The values you want for your example are:

```
 ☑ Columns
    Number: 1
 ☑ Rows
    Number: 1
 ☑ Margin
    Top: 20px
    Left: 20px
    Bottom: 20px
    Right: 20px
```

Answer (score -2):

You can drag new guides from the rulers on all sides of the canvas. Just click and drag from there.